# EF7 One-to-many mapping

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I'm trying to map two classes using Entity Framework 7.0.0-rc1-final. Here's my classes:

```
    public class ParentClass
    {
            public ParentClass() { }

            [Key]
            public Int32 Id { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public String Field { get; set; }

            public List<ChildClass> Children { get; set; }

    }

    public class ChildClass
    {
        [Key]
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }

        public Int32 ParentID { get; set; }

        public ParentClass Parent { get; set; }
    }
```

and I have a mapping code in my context class with Fluent API:

```
    builder.Entity<ChildClass>().HasOne(x => x.Parent)
           .WithMany(x => x.Children).HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentID);
```

Then I add couple of ParentClass instances with children and save them to DB. They are saved to DB and look good in the DB, but when I'm trying to get list of  ParentClass children I always have null list:

```
var data = _context.ParentInstances.ToList();
data[any].Children == null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the fact that you want to include the children in query
Try:

```
var data = _context.ParentInstances.Include(p => p.Children).ToList();
```

**Edit:**

For make sure to add a reference to Microsoft.Data.Entity

Comment: Many thanks, that worked. Needed to reference Microsoft.Data.Entity to use Include method

Comment: glad to have helped. I updated the answer with your comment about the required reference